# iOS Map: Deselect Annotation Only on Map Click

Tags: ios, mkmapview, uigesturerecognizer, mkannotation

I have  map with annotations and some buttons and views around it. I'm using didSelectAnnotationView and didDeelectAnnotationView but deselect appears to be called anytime anything on screen is clicked, including my buttons. Is there a way to only have deselect fired only when a click is on the map and not on a button or somewhere else?